# Does DDR RAM also have a minimum bandwidth?

Tags: memory, speed, bandwidth

Reading about [DDR3 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) I can see that it has a peak data transfer rate. However, I assume the peak rate to be a theoretical maximum.

Can we also derive a minimum transfer rate for DDR3 RAM, given I'd know all the specs like bus clock, timings etc.? If so, how do I calculate that minimum transfer rate?

Comment: My guess would be that the worst "reasonable" case with a single rank would be a sequence of single reads to different rows within a single DRAM bank (a sequence of ACTIVATE, READ, PRECHARGE commands to the same bank) with the added overhead of occasional REFRESH commands (some of which are to other banks, allowing some parallel operation). If burst chop is used (which is pushing reasonableness), the bandwidth would be halved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, minimum would be easy enough to calculate. its 0 (regardless of unit of measure). I'm sure that sounds trite, but consider, RAM is dumb circuitry, with essentially no internal intelligence. All the smarts as it were, are on the motherboard and CPU.

As such, RAM is always operating at the max speed the system around it will allow it to function at, up to the max bandwidth (which once again is a matter of electrical engineering tolerances, not an intentional arbitrary cap).

To read RAM, the CPU populates the [Memory Address Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address_register) with the address of the data it wants, and the memory controller fills the [Memory Data Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_data_register) with the block of data at that address. Ultimately the rate at which the CPU drives these operations by working with the MAR/MDR will determine the speed with which the memory can be accessed to a much greater degree than the rate at which the MDR can be populated with the retrieved data from memory.

Comment: I think the question is assuming "under load".

Comment: but the answer is the same. RAM is an electrical circuit, so electricity passes through it like water through a pipe. The clock frequency the ram runs at is a property of the bus from CPU to RAM, not a property of the RAM module itself (other than that it has been constructed to carry power throughout the logical circuit in less than one tick at a given frequency). The frequency of the RAM does not change, nor does the bus width or bank count, all of which are driving factors for the bandwidth calculation, so min == max, or min = 0; take your pick.

Comment: "Under load" means making accesses (i.e., an arbitrarily long queue of ordered accesses is available). Under a particularly perverse access pattern (e.g., involving same bank different row accesses) the achieved bandwidth is much lower than the best case where the same row is accessed multiple times and different banks are accessed (which can even allow refreshing to be done in parallel). Max bandwidth assumes best case access pattern, min bandwidth assumes worst case access pattern.

Comment: be that as it may, that cannot be calculated as a result of the DDR3 specification variables. The bandwidth has not changed at all, just the degree to which your task can use it. Bandwidth is always calculated as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bandwidth the question of min or max is really kind of meaningless.